# why don't set the placeholder attribute for contact field?

Tags: hooks, forms

this is my `hook_form_alter` function for set the placeholder attribute and other stuff:

```
 function mysubtheme_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    switch ($form_id) {
        case 'contact_site_form':
            $form['tel'] = array(
                '#title' => t('Tél'),
                '#type' => 'textfield',
                '#required' => TRUE,
            );
            if ($form_id == 'contact_site_form') {
                $form['name']['#title'] = t('name/family name');
                $form['name']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Enter your name');
            }
                $order = array(
                '1' => 'name',
                '2' => 'mail',
                '3' => 'tel',
                '4' => 'subject',
                '5' => 'message',
                '6' => 'copy',
            );
            foreach ($order as $key => $field) {
               $form[$field]['#weight'] = $key;
            }
            break;
       }
  }
```

why don't set the placeholder attribute for contact field?

`kpr()` for this element shows:

[image]

Comment: What does `kpr($form['name'])` show you?

Comment: I edit the question.

Comment: What I asked you to do was to output the part of form you want to modify, so we could see what's actually there before you modify it. Here is a demo page about doing it: http://ratatosk.net/drupal/tutorials/debugging-drupal.html Sorry if I wasn't clear first time.

Comment: I received this result: (http://tb23.Trainbit.com/d/8065691884.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this line to code and the problem was solved:

```
 $form['name']['#default_value'] ='';
```

Edited code is:

```
if ($form_id == 'contact_site_form') {
    $form['name']['#title'] = t('name/family name');
    $form['name']['#default_value'] ='';
    $form['name']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Enter your name');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

edit

```
$form['name']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = array(t('Enter your name'));
```

to

```
$form['name']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Enter your name');
```

then execute "flush all caches"

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Comment: try to flush cache,My test is ok

Comment: I flush all caches but still doesn't work.

Comment: what file the mysubtheme_form_alter function is writted in?

Comment: In mysubtheme template.php file.

Comment: you should write it in module,for example,hello.module file in hello module

Comment: Not true, all `_alter` hooks can be implemented at the theme level

Comment: Further explain, please.

Comment: Clive's comment is right

Comment: Further explain Clive, please.